# Обрезка блоков в html

Tags: css, html5, css3, html

Как обрезать блоки так, как это показано на картинке? Я делал это через градиенты, но он получился не особо функциональным.[image: Пример]

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что значит обрезать? Непонятно, что имеется ввиду.

Comment: Блок с цифрой обрезан в форме пятиугольника и необходимо сделать что-то подобное

Comment: Статья вам в помощь [Геометрические фигуры на CSS](https://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/)

Answer (score 5):

Идея следующая: создаётся прямоугольник с нужным содержимым, к нему псевдоэлементом добавляется треугольник с нужной стороны. Строится треугольник через свойство border - длина бордера на каждой стороне форму треугольника.

В примере ниже выделил разными цветами для наглядности:

```css
.main {
  width: 100px; height: 50px;
  background: tomato;          /* основной цвет заливки фона */
}
.main:after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  top: 0; left: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 0px; height: 0px;
  border: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: pink;     /* основной цвет заливки фона */
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```